# Using Python3's datetime to format a date-time as per server's response's format

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

```
>>> mtime
1634725796.7212281
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(mtime)
datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 20, 15, 59, 56, 721228)
>>>
```

I want date-time string returned exactly in the format `Date: Wed, 20 Oct 2021 15:59:56 GMT` which is the format a server sends when the page was last modified.
https://serverfault.com/questions/168345/sending-content-message-body-along-with-304-not-modified-header

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Don't forget to set GMT; `datetime.fromtimestamp(mtime, tz=timezone.utc)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) function to format the datetime.

**If your datetime doesn't have a timezone:**

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> FORMAT_STR = "Date: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"

>>> example_time = datetime(2021, 10, 20, 15, 59, 56, 721228)

>>> formatted_time = example_time.strftime(FORMAT_STR)

>>> print(formatted_time)
Date: Wed, 20 Oct 2021 15:59:56
```

**If your datetime object is timezone aware:**

Use the `%Z` format option to get the timezone in the format string.

Comment: This is risky, you're completely ignoring whether or not the datetime is actually GMT (or timezone-aware at all).

Comment: This is more straight-forward : `from email.utils import formatdate; print(formatdate(mtime, usegmt=True))`

Comment: @jonrsharpe That is true, but the timezone info isn't available from the timestamp. That is dependent on the system and needs to be fetched from the OS.

Comment: A timestamp _is_ in UTC, by definition. But my point is that your answer shows a naive datetime, which will be _local_, and just slaps a possibly-incorrect "GMT" on the end. The comment by MrFuppes above shows how to create an aware datetime from a timestamp, for example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was skeptic about the hardcoded GMT myself. I've updated my answer.